# $_GET doesn't work

Tags: php, parameters, get

I have a really odd problem with $_GET. I'm fairly new to the HTML/CSS/PHP/MySQL stack. I've not used $_GET before and I'm trying to write a page that is used by a link in an email that confirms the user's email. The link contains a single parameter which is a GUID that I cross-reference against a database entry. While developing this, I've had problems getting hold of the $_GET parameters, so I've cut the page down to a test page thus:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hullo.<br/>
        <?php
            echo $_GET['testparam'];
        ?>
        <br/>
        World.
        <br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am then calling this with:

```
http://mywebsite/dev/test.html?testparam=2
```

I get the following output:

> Hullo.
>
> World.

What is going on? I cannot make the test simpler. I'm using PHP 7.1 if that helps. Any advice very gratefully received.

Comment: `.html` files are not normally parsed as php scripts. You need a script with for example the `.php` extension.

Comment: Can you `var_dump($_GET);` ? I'd like to see what happens.

Comment: the file needs to be .php

Comment: @RonnieOosting the problem is that he's using .html extension

Comment: @azjezz Yes, I see it now. :)

Comment: If you view the source in the web browser you'll probably see your PHP code is still there and has not been run.

Comment: Apache or nginx? Rewrite rules?

Comment: Thanks everyone - it is the fact that the page had an html and not php extension. I've marked as answer the top answer that reflects this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure your page is interpretted as PHP by the server until you declare .html files to be interpretted as PHP (in apache or whatever).

Write <-?php echo "2"; ?> in your page to be sure.

REname your page test.php and it should work if it's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have run the test on my server setup and get the following response:

```
Hullo.
2
World.
```

So it may be a case that PHP isn't configured properly. To test this try something such as setting a variable then printing it.

```
<?PHP
$x = 2;
echo $x;
?>
```

if this fails then read the PHP installation docs to make sure you have it installed correctly.
http://php.net/manual/en/install.php

EDIT:

Just noticed you are trying to do it off a HTML page. The page needs extension: .php .php5 .php7 and such.

Read here: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php